# Read all integers from string c++

Tags: c++, c, string, integer

I need some help with getting all the integers from a std::string and getting each of those integer into an int variable.

String example:

```
<blah> hi 153 67 216
```

I would like the program to ignore the "blah" and "hi" and store each of the integers into an int variable. So it comes out to be like:

```
a = 153
b = 67
c = 216
```

Then i can freely print each separately like:

```
printf("First int: %d", a);
printf("Second int: %d", b);
printf("Third int: %d", c);
```

Thanks!

Comment: Search this website. This has been asked and answered thousands of times.

Comment: What is `<blah>` supposed to be?

Comment: @0x499602D2 it could be anything "sdnjid blah hi 23 35 2" it was just an example

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can create your own function that manipulates a `std::ctype` facet by using its `scan_is` method. Then you can return the generated string to a `stringstream` object and insert the contents to your integers:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <locale>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <cstring>

std::string extract_ints(std::ctype_base::mask category, std::string str, std::ctype<char> const& facet)
{
    using std::strlen;

    char const *begin = &str.front(),
               *end   = &str.back();

    auto res = facet.scan_is(category, begin, end);

    begin = &res[0];
    end   = &res[strlen(res)];

    return std::string(begin, end);
}

std::string extract_ints(std::string str)
{
    return extract_ints(std::ctype_base::digit, str,
         std::use_facet<std::ctype<char>>(std::locale("")));
}

int main()
{
    int a, b, c;

    std::string str = "abc 1 2 3";
    std::stringstream ss(extract_ints(str));

    ss >> a >> b >> c;

    std::cout << a << '\n' << b << '\n' << c;
}
```

> Output:
>
> 1
>   2
>   3

***[Demo](http://ideone.com/NWcOvv)***

Comment: ...but It's missing `#include <iterator>` for `std::back_inserter`

Comment: @Mike Yes, this code will work for gcc-4.7.2+. Is this code not compiling for you? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is not compiling, im using gcc-4.2.1

Comment: @Mike Replace the `auto` with `char const*`.

Comment: @0x499602D2 now its 2 errors:
'struct std::string' has no member named 'front'
and
'struct std::string' has no member named 'back'

Comment: Wow, you should upgrade your compiler lol. Use `begin = &str[0];` instead of  `begin = &str.front()`  and `end = &str[str.size()]` instead of `end = &str.back()`. Also, change `ctype<char>>` to `ctype<char> >` (a space must go between the tokens).

Comment: @0x499602D2 Haha im compiling on iOS using theos thats why my compiler is not updated. Also, thanks it worked!

Comment: @user664303 *What* is outputting strings? I'm  outputting *integers* to standard output.

Comment: My mistake. Comment deleted.

Answer (score 1):

- Use `std::isdigit()` to check whether a character is a digit. Until space is not reached, add stepwise to a separate `string`.
- Then use `std::stoi()` to convert your string to an int.
- Clear the content of the string using `clear()` method.
- Go to first step

Repeat until the end of the base string is not reached.

Answer (score 1):

First use [string tokenizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55680/2436175)

```
std::string text = "token, test   153 67 216";

char_separator<char> sep(", ");
tokenizer< char_separator<char> > tokens(text, sep);
```

Then, if you do not know exactly how many values you will get, you shouldn't use single variables `a b c`, but an array like `int input[200]`, or better, a `std::vector`, which can adapt to the number of elements you read.

```
std::vector<int> values;
BOOST_FOREACH (const string& t, tokens) {
    int value;
    if (stringstream(t) >> value) //return false if conversion does not succeed
      values.push_back(value);
}

for (int i = 0; i < values.size(); i++)
  std::cout << values[i] << " ";
std::cout << std::endl;
```

You have to:

```
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream> //std::cout
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/tokenizer.hpp>
using boost::tokenizer;
using boost::separator;
```

By the way, if you are programming C++ you might want to avoid using `printf`, and prefer `std::cout`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    using namespace std;
   int n=8,num[8];
    string sentence = "10 20 30 40 5 6 7 8";
    istringstream iss(sentence);

  vector<string> tokens;
copy(istream_iterator<string>(iss),
     istream_iterator<string>(),
     back_inserter(tokens));

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     num[i]= atoi(tokens.at(i).c_str());
     }

     for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
     cout<<num[i];
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

To read a line of string and extract integer from it,

```
 getline(cin,str);
 stringstream stream(str);
 while(1)
  {
    stream>>int_var_arr[i];
    if(!stream)
          break;
    i++;
    }
   }
```

the integers are stored in int_var_arr[]